SwiftUI why does focusable not work on iPad?
I get a printout in the preview that focus has changed to true on iPhone and the background changes to indigo, but nothing prints at all on iPad, nor does the background change. I don't see why the iPad is different? Searched extensively and used AI but can't find anything about this at all.
import SwiftUI

struct SimpleFocusTestView: View {
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Text("Test Focus")
            .focusable()
            .focused($isFocused)
            .onAppear { isFocused = true }
            .onChange(of: isFocused) { oldValue, newValue in
                print("Focus changed: \(newValue)")
            }
            .background {
              if isFocused {
                Capsule()
                  .fill(.indigo)
                  .opacity(0.3)
              }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SimpleFocusTestView()
}


Observations more than a definitive answer based on testing with Xcode 16.0 & iPadOS 18.0 sims. At the time of writing I have not tested this on an iPad device with a physical keyboard. I shall and update this answer later.
Points when testing with a sim and the following:


The FocusState binding cannot be set to true whilst the sim setting "Connect Hardware Keyboard" is ticked - so when the app is opened in the sim the onAppear is called but the binding does not allow the FocusState to change. Similarly trying to set focussed with a button action will also not work. Unticking the option when the app opens or prior to tapping the button allows the FocusState to be set.

Once the FocusState is set the "Connect Hardware Keyboard" option is then ticked, the view does become focussed and the onKeyPress modifier works as expected.


The above leaves us with (i) headaches for testing with sims and perhaps (ii) problems with not being able to use onAppear for real iPadOS devices due to needing to set the FocusState when detecting that the physical keyboard has been attached/detached.
UPDATE:
Same behaviour on a real iPad device - could not set the FocusState whilst a physical hardware Bluetooth keyboard was connected. The keyboard had to be disconnected and after setting the state and reconnecting the keyboard it worked.
I also tested with multiple fields and the focused($focused, equals: ) modifier and again found that the FocusState could only be changed programmatically when the view(s) was/were visible and the hardware keyboard was disconnected.
I am going to try and use Apple's GCKeyboard class instead of SwiftUI focusable views due to the above limitations.
UPDATE 2: Here a snippet of code showing a GCKeyboard approach.
    import Combine
    import GameController

    // --- the following would go into your view model code ---

    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    // All connected keyboards are coalesced into one keyboard object, so notification
    // about connection/disconnection will only be delivered once until last keyboard
    // disconnects.
    
    NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: .GCKeyboardDidConnect)
        .sink { [weak self] notification in
            guard
                let self,
                let keyboard = notification.object as? GCKeyboard
            else { return }
            
            keyboard.keyboardInput?.keyChangedHandler = { _, key, keyCode, pressed in
                // process
                print("in handler \(key) \(keyCode) \(pressed)")
            }
            
            print("did connect \(notification)")
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    
    
    NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: .GCKeyboardDidDisconnect)
        .sink { [weak self] notification in
            guard let self else { return }
            
            // anything you might need to do to clean
            // up states
            
            print("did disconnect \(notification)")
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)


Thanks for looking into this. So far I'm quite surprised at the response I've had posting this at various places. I've been unable to confirm if anyone else is able to get the simple code I posted to work, until you posted this. So it's a bug? Why isn't Apple aware of this? I had a response from one of the Apple team at the apple developer forums who asked me to first test something but then never replied again. For my use I actually only need this working on the simulator since it's for easy debugging and running tests using key presses.

@Hasen It seems more deliberate than a bug. It is frustrating because the various example about using the focusable() and focussed($state) modifiers do not mention the iPad device limitations. I have shall update my answer to give you the GCKeyboard approach, which needs more effort but is reliable approach for capturing hardware keyboard responses.

Deliberate? Why would it be deliberate though? I don't see what it achieves. I can't see you've mentioned the reason anywhere so if you could add into your answer why they'd want to have this limitation specific to iPad there and the benefits of it that would be good. I also use flutter and I've never seen any of these kinds of limitations specific to ipad. I added debugging key presses to flutter and they work fine with both iphone and ipad. Without being able to focus there's no way to use swift's onKeyPress method.

@Hasen Deliberate in the sense that there is continuity of this across both iPadOS 17 and 18 and that Apple has not made any timely effort to update the behaviour. My reply leans towards being observational without being a definitive answer and I suspect only Apple engineers could justify the current behaviour. And as you (and I on other occasions) have experienced, their forum engineers sometimes give a prompt response without following up when it gets more involved. Like you I am frustrated with the behaviour but I feel reluctantly inclined to think Apple has an unstated reason.

Deliberate means they went out of their way to make it like this but what you're describing is they haven't gone out of their way to fix it. That would make it a bug that has not been fixed. It would only be deliberate if there were some reason why it needed to be like that, which it seems there is not. Bugs that don't get fixed even after countless complaints are common across all commercial software. Especially one like this which nobody even seems to be talking about except me. No point being frustrated about it when it's not even been reported as a bug yet..

The issue you're experiencing with your SwiftUI application likely stems from the differences in how iOS handles focus states between the iPhone and the iPad, especially concerning the use of focus in SwiftUI.
Differences in Focus Handling

iPad vs. iPhone: The iPad has different focus behavior, especially since it supports keyboard navigation and a larger variety of input methods. The focus might not automatically change to your view on the iPad the same way it does on an iPhone.

Focusable Views: On an iPad, elements can receive focus based on user interaction (like keyboard events), and if there's no physical keyboard attached, the behavior may differ. This means that the .onAppear { isFocused = true } might not be sufficient to change the focus state on the iPad.


I recommend you try these.

Use Focusable Modifier: Make sure your view is truly focusable. The Text view is not directly focusable; you may need to wrap it in a different interactive view, like Button, Rectangle, or anything that confirms focusability more.

Force Focus Change: Instead of setting the focus state directly in onAppear, you might want to use a more interactive approach (e.g., with a Button) to simulate the action.

Keyboard Support: Make sure to test with a keyboard attached to the iPad as it may significantly affect the focus behavior.


///////////////////
import SwiftUI  

struct SimpleFocusTestView: View {  
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool  

    var body: some View {  
        VStack {  
            Button("Test Focus") {  
                isFocused = true  
            }  
            .focusable()  
            .focused($isFocused)  
            .onChange(of: isFocused) { oldValue, newValue in  
                print("Focus changed: \(newValue)")  
            }  
            .background {  
                if isFocused {  
                    Capsule()  
                        .fill(Color.indigo)  
                        .opacity(0.3)  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        .onAppear {  
            // Explicitly request focus for iPad (conditionally if you want)  
            DispatchQueue.main.async {  
                isFocused = true  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}  

#Preview {  
    SimpleFocusTestView()  
}

I hope this could be helpful.

Thanks for responding, I thought nobody would. Unfortunately I already tried all of those, including using Button rather than Text. I already tried to solve it with ChatGPT and also Claude and they suggested similar things to you. I'm surprised I could find nothing online about this issue anywhere, especially since it's the most basic view setup just to test this. Are you able to get it to work on iPad? I tried both in the simulator and in the preview window, the iPad behaviour really is completely different to the iPhone.
